# how to make child list elements horizontal and take full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested list structure in my dom. I want the child list elements to be listed horizontally and take full width. How can I achieve this?
My code

```css
.workicons-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
}
.workicons-list li {
    float: left;
   max-width:224px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.workicons-sub-list {
      padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.workicons-sub-list li {
     float:left;
    max-width:224px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="options-row">
          
            <ul class="workicons-list">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    
                      <ul class="workicons-sub-list">
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
            </ul>
           
            
        </div>
```

This is How it looks in full screen
[image]
And this is how I want it to be
[image]

Comment: if you are using bootstrap you could go with their grid system :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic I have tried it first and failed, I want second list to be nested inside first. Like six col-md-2 inside one col-md-12 and second list will have another six col-md-2 inside each col-md-2 . IF you could show , how to do it in grid way, I am more than happy. But I don't want to fix the position of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.workicons-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.workicons-list li {
    float: left;
   max-width:224px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.workicons-list li.expanded {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.workicons-sub-list {
      padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:235px;
  left:0;
  width: 100%
    
}
.workicons-sub-list li {
     float:left;
    max-width:224px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="options-row">
          
            <ul class="workicons-list">
                <li class="expanded"><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    
                      <ul class="workicons-sub-list">
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s31.postimg.org/a6irdmg5n/cleaner.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/8t9ekfovp/brush.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
            </ul>
           
            
        </div>
```

Your .workicons-list li  is set to max-width of 224, so anything inside it will by default be only that wide. And, with float on, it'll just tile the inner menu items down. You may need to add a class to the parent li of the opened nested menu so you can override its width to 100%, or whatever width.

Also, not sure if the desired behavior is for the submenu to be ontop of the parent menu when expanded?

Comment: Desired behaviour is submenu below first menu. Can you please add a sample code on how you plan it. I am unable to understand what you are saying

Comment: Added code above that gets you close. Since you want the submenu below, you have to set a relative position from the main menu, and absolutely position the submenu(s) under relative to the main. Doing that auto-gives you full width.